# R - Random Forest and more than 53 categories

Tags: r, random-forest

I know. RandomForest is not able to handle more than 53 categories. Sadly I have to analyze data and one column has 165 levels. Therefor I want to use RandomForest for a classification.

My problem is I cannot remove this columns since this predictor is really important and known as a valuable predictor.

This predictor has 165 levels and is a factor.

Are there any tips how I can handle this? Since we are talking about film genre I have no idea.

Are there alternative packages for big data? A special workaround? Something like this..

Switching to Python is no option. We have too many R scripts here.

Thanks a lot and all the best

The str(data) looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   481696 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ SENDERNR          : int  432 1612 735 721 436 436 1321 721 721 434 ...
 $ SENDER            : Factor w/ 14 levels "ARD Das Erste",..: 6 3 4 9 12 12 10 9 9 7 ...
 $ GEPLANTE_SENDUNG_N: Factor w/ 12563 levels "-- nicht bekannt --",..: 7070 808 5579 9584 4922 4922 12492 1933 9584 4533 ...
 $ U_N_PROGRAMMCODE  : Factor w/ 14 levels "Bühne/Aufführung",..: 9 4 8 4 8 8 12 8 4 2 ...
 $ U_N_PROGRAMMSPARTE: Factor w/ 6 levels "Anderes","Fiction",..: 5 3 2 3 2 2 5 2 3 3 ...
 $ U_N_SENDUNGSFORMAT: Factor w/ 29 levels "Bühne / Aufführung",..: 20 9 19 4 19 19 24 19 4 16 ...
 $ U_N_GENRE         : Factor w/ 163 levels "Action / Abenteuer",..: 119 147 115 4 158 158 163 61 4 84 ...
 $ U_N_PRODUKTIONSART: Factor w/ 5 levels "Eigen-, Co-, Auftragsproduktion, Cofinanzierung",..: 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ U_N_HERKUNFTSLAND : Factor w/ 25 levels "afrikanische Länder",..: 16 16 25 16 15 15 16 25 16 16 ...
 $ GEPLANTE_SENDUNG_V: Factor w/ 12191 levels "-- nicht bekannt --",..: 6932 800 5470 9382 1518 9318 12119 1829 9382 4432 ...
 $ U_V_PROGRAMMCODE  : Factor w/ 13 levels "Bühne/Aufführung",..: 9 4 8 4 8 8 12 8 4 2 ...
 $ U_V_PROGRAMMSPARTE: Factor w/ 6 levels "Anderes","Fiction",..: 5 3 2 3 2 2 5 2 3 3 ...
 $ U_V_SENDUNGSFORMAT: Factor w/ 28 levels "Bühne / Aufführung",..: 20 9 19 4 19 19 24 19 4 16 ...
 $ U_V_GENRE         : Factor w/ 165 levels "Action / Abenteuer",..: 119 148 115 4 160 19 165 61 4 84 ...
 $ U_V_PRODUKTIONSART: Factor w/ 5 levels "Eigen-, Co-, Auftragsproduktion, Cofinanzierung",..: 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ U_V_HERKUNFTSLAND : Factor w/ 25 levels "afrikanische Länder",..: 16 16 25 16 15 9 16 25 16 16 ...
 $ ABGELEHNT         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AKZEPTIERT        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: you might find answers to [R's randomForest can not handle more than 32 levels. What is workaround?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49243/rs-randomforest-can-not-handle-more-than-32-levels-what-is-workaround) useful.

Comment: Hey @ImranAli I checked this page a few days ago. Sadly this workaround ist not helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Having faced the same issue, here are some tips I can list.

1. **Switch to another algorithm**, for instance gradient boosting from
   `gbm` package. You can handle up to 1024 categorical levels. If your predictor has quite discriminant parameters, you should also consider probabilistic approaches such as `naiveBayes`.
2. **Transform your predictor into dummy variables**, which can be done by using `matrix.model`. You can then perform a random forest over this matrix.
3. **Reduce the number of levels in your factor**. Ok, that may sound like a silly advice, but is it really relevant to look at factors with such "thinness" ? Is it possible for you to aggregate some modalities at a broader level ?

**EDIT TO ADD MODEL.MATRIX EXAMPLE**

As mentioned, here is an example on how to use `model.matrix` to transform your column into dummy variables.

```
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C")),
                   var2 = factor(c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Z")),
                   target = c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
dummyMat <- model.matrix(target ~ var1 + var2, mydf, # set contrasts.arg to keep all levels
                         contrasts.arg = list(var1 = contrasts(mydf$var1, contrasts = F), 
                                             var2 = contrasts(mydf$var2, contrasts = F))) 
mydf2 <- cbind(mydf, dummyMat[,c(2:ncol(dummyMat)]) # just removing intercept column
```

Comment: Thanks @AshOfFire Point 3 is sadly not possible. Tip 2: I checked the model.matrix method but I guess I am to stupid for this. At the moment we ware talking about a data.frame and one column with more than 53 levels. When I extract this column and transform the values to a matrix, how can I use this new generated matrix in combination with the initial data? I will check out the gbm package.

Comment: Once you have transformed your factor column into dummy variables, you just need to combine its columns to your initial data frame (you will keep the same number of rows if using `model.matrix`). I will edit my post to show you an example on how to use it.

Comment: Ah, I got the point. As shown in your example I will get a data.frame called mydf2 with some additional columns. So I can use this new generated data.frame and extract the columns I need. In this case just remove the columns called "var1" and "var2". Makes sense. But do you think RandomForest is helpful for so many factors regarding the run-time? Do you have experiences? You mentioned the package GBM... THANKS A LOT!

Comment: You may indeed face run time issues (considering the volume you're treating). Depending on the purpose of your classification, you may have to drop RF and consider alternatives. In my case, I had 5 predictors, including one with ~800 factors and one with ~60 factors (couldn't reduce them) + 100k observations. I used `gbm` on a single-core laptop and the script took roughly 10-15 minutes. It happened, though, that `naiveBayes` gave much quicker (and nicer) results since in a couple of seconds (ironically, the combination of those two predictors was very discriminant), so I stuck to this method.

Comment: @AshOfFire : will the code you provided in the answer work for continuous and categorical variables together?

Comment: @Noob no this is oriented towards categorical variable. If you have continuous variables, I suggest you perform bucketing beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Use the caret package :

```
random_forest <- train("***dependent variable name***" ~ ., 
                 data = "***your training data set***", 
                 method = "ranger")
 This can handle 53 + categories.
```