# Categorical Variable has a Limit of 53 Values

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to fit a "Random Forest" (a statistical model) to my data, but the problem is : one of my categorical variables has more than 53 categories - apparently the "random forest" package in R does not permit the user to have more than 53 categories, and this is preventing me from using this variable in my model. Ideally, I would like to use this variable.

To illustrate this example, I created a data set (called "data") where one of the variables has more than 53 categories:

```
#load libraries
library(caret)
library(randomforest)
library(ranger)

#first data set

cat_var <- c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", 
"s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff",
 "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", "zz", "aaa", "bbb")

var_1 <- rnorm(54,10,10)
var_2 <- rnorm(54, 5, 5)
var_3 <- rnorm(54, 6,18)

response <- c("a","b")
response <- sample(response, 54, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

data_1 = data.frame(cat_var, var_1, var_2, var_3, response)
data_1$response = as.factor(data_1$response)
data_1$cat_var = as.factor(data_1$cat_var)

#second data set


cat_var <- c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", 
"s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff",
 "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", "zz", "aaa", "bbb")

var_1 <- rnorm(54,10,10)
var_2 <- rnorm(54, 5, 5)
var_3 <- rnorm(54, 6,18)

response <- c("a","b")
response <- sample(response, 54, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

data_2 = data.frame(cat_var, var_1, var_2, var_3, response)
data_2$response = as.factor(data_2$response)
data_2$cat_var = as.factor(data_2$cat_var)

# third data set


cat_var <- c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", 
"s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff",
 "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", "zz", "aaa", "bbb")

var_1 <- rnorm(54,10,10)
var_2 <- rnorm(54, 5, 5)
var_3 <- rnorm(54, 6,18)

response <- c("a","b")
response <- sample(response, 54, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

data_3 = data.frame(cat_var, var_1, var_2, var_3, response)
data_3$response = as.factor(data_3$response)
data_3$cat_var = as.factor(data_3$cat_var)

#combine data sets

data = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3)
```

From here, I am interested in fitting the random forest model. I looked at different stackoverflow posts (e.g. [R randomForest too many categories error even with fewer than 53 categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161856/r-randomforest-too-many-categories-error-even-with-fewer-than-53-categories) ,  [R - Random Forest and more than 53 categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914490/r-random-forest-and-more-than-53-categories)), and here is what I noticed.

Here is what happens if you try to fit the random forest model as is:

```
#random forest using the "Randomforest" library

rf = randomForest(response ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + cat_var, data=data, ntree=50, mtry=2)

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

In one of these posts, a user suggested using the "caret" library to fit the model - apparently the caret model does not have the 53 category limitation. This works, but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
#random forest using the "caret" and "ranger" libraries: (are these correct?)

random_forest <- train(response ~., 
                 data = data, 
                 method = 'ranger')

random_forest <- train(response ~., 
                 data = data, 
                 method = 'rf')
```

Finally, another user suggested using the "model matrix" approach, but I am not sure if I understood this approach all together:

```
#model matrix method


dummyMat <- model.matrix(response ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + cat_var, data, # set contrasts.arg to keep all levels
                         contrasts.arg = list(var_1 = contrasts(data$var_1, contrasts = T),  var_3 = contrasts(data$var_3, contrasts = T),  cat_var = contrasts(data$cat_var, contrasts = F)
                                             var_2 = contrasts(data$var2, contrasts = T))) 
data2 <- cbind(data, dummyMat[,c(4:ncol(dummyMat)]) # just removing intercept column

rf = randomForest(response ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + cat_var, data=data2, ntree=50, mtry=2)
```

Can someone please suggest how can I solve this problem? Is the second approach (using "caret") correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that the `caret` approach is correct. `caret` contains tools for data splitting, preprocessing, feature selection and model tuning with resampling cross-validation. Here I post a typical workflow for fitting a model with the `caret` package (example with the data you posted).

First, we set a cross-validation method for tuning the hyperparameters of the chosen model (in your case the tuning parameters are `mtry` for both `ranger` and `randomForest`, `splitrule` and `min.node.size` for `ranger`). In the example, I choose a [k-fold corss-validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) with k=10

```
library(caret)
control <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 10)
```

then we create a grid with the possible values that the parameters to be tuned can assume

```
rangergrid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:(ncol(data)-1),splitrule="extratrees",min.node.size=seq(0.1,1,0.1))
rfgrid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:(ncol(data)-1))
```

finally, we fit the chosen models:

```
random_forest_ranger <- train(response ~., 
                       data = data, 
                       method = 'ranger',
                       trControl=control,
                       tuneGrid=rangergrid)


random_forest_rf <- train(response ~., 
                       data = data, 
                       method = 'rf',
                       trControl=control,
                       tuneGrid=rfgrid)
```

the output of the `train` function look like this:

```
> random_forest_rf
Random Forest 

162 samples
  4 predictor
  2 classes: 'a', 'b' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 146, 146, 146, 145, 146, 146, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa      
  2     0.6852941   0.00000000
  3     0.6852941   0.00000000
  4     0.6602941  -0.04499494

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

For more info on the `caret` package look a the online [vignette](https://topepo.github.io/caret/)

Comment: thank you for your answer! this confirms what I had in mind!